# Strange numbers in "Create your own urdf file" URDF's tutorial

Tags: ros, urdf, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I recently started studying ROS and now I'm considering [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Create%20your%20own%20urdf%20file)

I don't understand how the **axis xyz** values (from Completing the Kinematics) was calculated.
The follow values are given at first:

```
  <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
```

for joint2 and

```
<axis xyz="-0.707 0.707 0" />
```

for joint1.

But after that in the general .XML file are given:

```
 <axis xyz="-0.707 0.707 0" />
```

for joint2 and

```
<axis xyz="-0.9 0.15 0" />
```

for joint1.

As i know vectors for axis xyz should be normalized, but "-0.9 0.15 0" is not normalized.
What are the correct values? Thanks.

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS kinetic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278156/strange-numbers-in-%22create-your-own-urdf-file%22-urdf%27s-tutorial/) by [SerSav](https://answers.ros.org/users/33019/sersav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-12-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-26**:
Just divide each each component by the magnitude. Then, perhaps, you can update the wiki to help others out.

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2018-01-26**:
I think it's an error since 0 1 0 is already normalized. It should be 0 1 0 in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to my view it depends on your joint type if it is revolute or translational joint.
Ex. if your joint is revolute and axis of rotation is around z axis, simply put

---

Originally posted by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) with karma: 80 on 2018-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0